# Convolutional neural network for non-image data

Tags: algorithms, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, neural-networks

I am working on a project for the prediction of preeclampsia, and one of the algorithms to be used is the convolutional neural network. I am a beginner in machine learning, and I  am struggling to find out "**whether is it applicable to use the convolutional neural network for numerical data. without the need to convert it to images first?**".
if yes, please provide me with some resources to know how.

thank you.

Comment: It can make sense to use a CNN on a 1D signal. Not much on heterogenous data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the input to a neural network is just a bunch of numbers.  An image is treated as a bunch of numbers, one number for each pixel.

That said, a convolutional neural network might or might not be the right tool, depending on the nature of your data.  CNNs are good for working with 1D sequences of numbers or 2D arrays/matrices of numbers, especially if you expect that they should have some time-invariance or translation-invariance properties (e.g., a pattern that occurs this week is also interesting if it occurred last week).  It's not the right tool if you have a feature vector that is an assortment of unrelated features; in that case, a fully connected neural network is probably more appropriate.

There is *lots* of basic information about CNNs available on the Internet.  I suggest finding yourself some tutorials and studying how they work.